# Binary search + Sorting vs. Linear search (Big O)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, binary-search, linear-search

i have a question on a problem i am working on. I have to play Videos randomly in order without repeating a video. Each video is only allowed to be played once per playlist. Each video has an unique id from 0 up to max_video_count which is determined on runtime (depending on the server).

What i do now is, i created a linked list which adds the unique id of each video played. Than i create randomly a random number between 0 and max_video_count , do linear search if the number is already in the linked list and if yes i calculate a new number.. and again linear search .. and so on!!

obvisiouly this isn't very practical and sometimes it takes way to long to find an element. especially when a lot of videos were played already.

So i thought, i implement binear search instead of linear search but that brings me to the problem that i have to sort the list first. So, my next step was to think, that i sort the list while inserting the new unique_id and than do binary search.

I know that binary search is O(log n) compared to O(n) linear search which is a great advancement. But sorting the list is also O(n) because to find the right spot i would have to do linear search again..... So i come to the solution than that binary search would be O(log N * n) compared to O(n) linear search -> linear search fast. Is that right? Maybe my whole approach is wrong.. but i couldn't come up with something better yet...

I am quite new to algorithms so it would be nice if someone could enlighten me here :-)

Greetings
Markus

Comment: Is it OK to repeat each video *once*?

Comment: videos are not allowed to be played twice..

Comment: Ah, that's not what your post says... moral: when asking something technical where the details matter, pay attention to detail :-)

Comment: Sounds illogical: sorting just because you want randomness. How about removing the vidios from the "to_be_seen list" and putting them on a "seen" list, once they are seen?

Comment: as i said, if someone knows a better solution... :-) i think i accept the answer from Kerrek SB as this seems to be a way more efficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: A linked list is a lousy data structure for real world stuff. The only practical use is in teaching ;-)

Comment: What's your language, by the way? C++ has [`std::random_shuffle`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) and `std::vector`, which should allow you to implement this in a few lines.

Comment: Your runtime complexities seem a bit of: Binary search is O(log(n) or O(n) if done on a linked list, linear search O(n) each iteration, so O(n*log(n)) (or O(n*n)) and O(n*n) for everything, while sorting is O(n*log(n)) (and I assume done only once), so it would be O(n*log(n)) (or O(n*n)) for sorting+bsearch and O(n*n) for linear search. So a linked list doesn't really make sense here, an array would be better. However the right datastructure would probably be a Hashset with O(1) lookup. Of course creating random permutations up front is still better, which is why this is just a comment

Comment: Actually due to repeated lookup when getting already played items it should be O(n^2) lookups resulting in runtimes of O(n^2*log(n)) for sorting+bsearch on an array, O(n^3) for both linear search and sorting+bsearch on linked list and O(n^2) for a hashset (which shows just how much more efficient it is to just premutate the list beforehand)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are essentially just looking at a **random permutation**. Arrange your videos in one fixed list, and then, to create the playlist, produce a random permutation of that list and play the permuted list.

A typical and efficient (O(n)) way to achieve such a permutation is via a Knuth Shuffle.

<sub>(Practically, you can of course just create a random permutation of an *index set* and play the items in order of the permuted indices.)</sub>

Comment: so i create and shuffle the list BEFORE playing the playlist? That would make sense actually :-)

Comment: Unless the list of videos changes over time.

Comment: Yes. The list is fixed once and for all, and you create a new, random index set via a shuffle of `[0, N)` each time you want to play the entire thing.

Comment: @asjo: If the list changes, you can accommodate for that, too: If it grows, just append `[N, N + k)` to your list and shuffle the remaining range (that you haven't played yet). If it shrinks, just skip the deleted items.

Comment: thanks :-) i will accept the answer in 5 minutes :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB - sure, but the chances of you messing that up is not inconsiderable. And the added ones wont get an equal chance among the videos not played yet.

Comment: @asjo: You mean me personally? I'm insulted :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the number of videos is fixed, you could just use an array of booleans, all initialized to false, to keep track of what have been played - constant time lookup. Or use integers, counting number of times played, if you want to limit the number of times instead.

If videos are removed from (or added to) the list over the course of playing, an associative array (in some languages called a dictionary or a hash) for keeping track of what has been played is probably easier.

Don't implement the structure yourself (unless that is the learning exercise you want), use what your language of choice has to offer.

Comment: thanks, the list will stay constant DURING the play.. it only changes when a new playlist gets played.